# Setting Bar width in plotly GO when x axis is datetime

Tags: datetime, plotly, bar-chart, width

The go.Bar object has a parameter `width`, which controls the width of the bars BUT it's in the units of the axis.

From the docs:

> width
> Sets the bar width (in position axis units)

This makes it impractical when working with datetime objects because then width=1 seems to equal 1 millisecond? Meaning that if you work with daily or weekly aggregations width needs to be set to very high values to control the width of the bars if you want to make them contiguous for example. E.g. I work with weekly data and to make bars contiguous I need to set it to the number of milliseconds in a week - width=6.048e+8...

It would be nice to have a parameter that controls the relative width, no?

Q: what is the best practice to easily change width of bar graphs when working with time? It's a hassle to convert milliseconds to the amount of time in days or weeks that the bar should span.

Q: any intuition behind this implementation? this doesn't seem practical?

plotly=5.15